# Add Specifications for products in magento

Tags: php, magento

I need to add specifications for certain products in product detail page from back end in magento, For example the specifications to be shown in frond  end

```
<h2>Specifications</h2>
<ul>
<li>Spacing: 3 to 20 feet (0,9 to 6,1 m).</li>
<li>Pressure: 15 to 70 psi (1 to 5 bar).</li>
<li>Regulates nozzle pressure to an average 30 psi (2.1 bar) with inlet pressures of up to 70 psi (4.8 bar).</li>
<li>Flow-by: 0 at 8 psi (0.6 bar) or greater; 0.1 gpm (0.02 m3/h; 0.006 l/s) otherwise.</li>

<li>Installation: bottom inlet.</li>
</ul>
<h2>Dimensions</h2>
<ul>
<li>1/2" (15/21) female threaded inlets</li>
<li>Body height: 6" (15,2 cm) body height; 4" pop-up height (10,2 cm)</li>
<li>Exposed surface diameter: 2 1/4" (5,7 cm) </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Hello you will create attribute for specification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello you will create attribute for specification

Answer (score 1):

If you create a new attribute for each item in the specification the Magento's default theme will show this as additional info in a nice table. Depending on your theme you could edit the table to display as you wish.

The benefit of doing your specification this way allows your products to be compared on each of the specification name:value pairs.

If none of that is an option then you can create one attribute called specification with an attribute code of spec_table and set the type as text area allowing you to enter the HTML you supplied. With this attribute set you can check for the field and output in your `product/view.phtml` file like so:

```
if($specTable = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('spec_table')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product)) { echo $specTable }
```